# Powershell get date add Weeks and show the remaining time left?

Tags: powershell

I am trying to create or get the result for the date and days with the Weeks, but somehow Powershell cannot do it for me:

**(Get-Date '29/2/2020').addweeks(18)**

The error I have received is like:

```
(New-TimeSpan -Start "$Get-Date" -End "(Get-Date '29/2/2020').addweeks(18)").ToString("dd' Days 'hh' Hours 'mm' Minutes 'ss' Seconds'")
Method invocation failed because [System.DateTime] does not contain a method named 'addweeks'.
At line:1 char:1
+ (Get-Date '29/2/2020').addweeks(18)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound
 
New-TimeSpan : Cannot bind parameter 'Start'. Cannot convert value "-Date" to type "System.DateTime". Error: "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."
At line:3 char:22
+ (New-TimeSpan -Start "$Get-Date" -End "(Get-Date '29/2/2020').addweek ...
+                      ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [New-TimeSpan], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewTimeSpanCommand
```

The output expected is:

```
Days, dd MM YYYY hh:mm AM/PM
"dd' Days 'hh' Hours 'mm' Minutes 'ss' Seconds'" remaining until the date entered.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`New-TimeSpan`'s `-Start` and `-End` parameters expect arguments of type `[DateTime]`, so you have to ensure your `Get-Date` commands get evaluated *before* being passed of to `New-TimeSpan`.

```
$now = Get-Date
$18WeeksFromLeapDay = (Get-Date '29/2/2020').AddDays($(18 * 7))

$timespan = New-TimeSpan -Start $now -End $18WeeksFromLeapDay
```

You can also omit the `-Start` argument completely and it will default to "right now" anyway:

```
$timespan = New-TimeSpan -End (Get-Date '29/2/2020').AddDays($(18 * 7))
```

I'd strongly suggest consulting the [`about_Parsing`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parsing) and [`about_Parameters`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parameters) help files to get a better understanding of how PowerShell evaluates command expressions and parameter arguments

Comment: Hi @mathias, somehow it throws error: Method invocation failed because [System.DateTime] does not contain a method named 'addweeks'.

Comment: @SeniorSystemsEngineer Use `.AddDays($($numberOfWeeks * 7))`

Comment: That is great. Thank you Mathias